# Python selenium problem with wait till element is clickable and with click link with javascript href

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I wrote script to get data from page and I try improve two functionality.
First: I want to change `time.sleep(10)` to

```
select = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.element_located_to_be_selected((By.NAME, 'capacityReport_length')))
```

but i get `"is not clickable at point (438,86) because another element <div class="mods-content-all-aisles"> obscures it".`

Also i can't click `<a href = "setting min" href="javascript:void(0)">`

Any advice ?

Comment: Add the html in question please.

Comment: You can attempt to remove the element that is overlaying the element you want to click.

Answer (score 1):

In order for an element to be directly clickable, it can't be obscured by another element. In the browser, the obscuring element (often the encapsulating element), takes the click event and may or may not pass it through to elements beneath it. In other words, the element you want to click is not *directly* clickable.

In this case, the element `<div class="mods-content-all-aisles">` is blocking you from directly clicking the element you want to click.

You can try to find the obscuring element and click *that* element at some location to get the behavior you want.

It could also be the case that your wait condition is not sufficient. You probably want to (additionally) use the `element_to_be_clickable` condition.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

Alternatively, you can try some of the following ideas:

using javascript to trigger the click:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", my_element)
```

You can also try using javascript to retrieve an element from coordinates and clicking it:

```
coords = (438, 86)
driver.execute_script("document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]).click()", *coords)
```

You could also try deleting the element that obscures the element you want to click, but that may end up deleting the element you want to click if it's nested inside of it.

Ultimately, it will be difficult to give definitive answer without the full contents of the page you're working with including the HTML and JS resources. But hopefully this guidance will help you arrive at the solution for this specific webpage.

Comment: Thanks for help me understanding how this works. Probably the case was some kind of animation which obscured element that I wanted to click. I just add time.sleep(2) after data was loaded and now it's work. But i still don't get why click on <a href = "setting min" href="javascript:void(0)> don't work.